# How to change individual properties of an object in $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If you have in the view something like:

```
<span ng-model="foo.bar1"></span>
<span ng-model="foo.bar2"></span>
<span ng-model="foo.bar3"></span>
```

Because how Angular maps the objects you cannot do in the controller something like:

```
$scope.foo.bar2 = "something";
```

Instead you need to do:

```
$scope.foo = {
  bar1: "value1",
  bar2: "something",
  bar3: "value2"
}
```

So, if I need to change only one property of that object I need to reassign the other values every time?

Comment: No need to. If you have initialized the object foo with default values, then you can access the individual properties of the object

Comment: Is this not working $scope.foo[bar1]="Updated value" ?

Comment: If you have `$scope.foo` initialized then you can do like `$scope.foo.bar2 = "something";`. And I guess you have that initialized already.

Comment: What do you mean by _"how Angular maps the objects"_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not required at all. All you need to do is initialize. Here's a sample piece of code below:

In controller

```
$scope.person ={
age: 30,
sex: 'male',
name: 'hero',
occupation: 'actor'
```

}

In HTML

```
 <h3>Person Details</h3>
 <p><input type="text" ng-model="person.occupation"></p>
   <span>{{person.name}},</span>
   <span>{{person.age}},</span>
   <span>{{person.sex}},</span>
   <span>{{person.occupation}}</span>
```

Now, if you keep changing the value in the textbox, it will keep reflecting in the person details below.

Answer (score 0):

If you have:

```
$scope.foo = {
  bar1: "bar1Value", // any initialization value for all 3
  bar2: "bar2Value",
  bar3: "bar3Value"
}
```

or simply

```
$scope.foo = {};
```

Then you can do :

```
$scope.foo.bar2 = "something";
```

After that initialization, wherever you want.